# Piwik Master/Slave database configuration

Tags: database, configuration, matomo, stunnel

Is it possible to configure a piwik installation to use one database server for writing and one for reading? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Piwik can not be configured in such way. This functionality requires a modification of source code.

P.S. You can try to use master-master replication for scalability.